# Prove $\chi(G) \le \ell + 1$, where $\ell$ is the length of a longest path in $G$.

Tags: graph-theory

Is it possible use The Gallai-Roy-Vitaver Theorem to prove the following result?

> For every orientation $D$ of a graph $G$, $\chi(G) \le 1 + l(D)$.

Is it correct to say that $l(G) \ge l(D)$, so by Gallai-Roy Theorem $\chi(G) \le 1 + l(G)$?

Comment: Any path on $G$ is also a path on at least one orientation of $G$, so this seems correct.

Comment: If you haven't been explicitly told to use that fact, then I believe the dual of $G$ may be worth considering.